# Anything interesting about Eigenvalues of sum of matrices $A+B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a skew-symmetric matrix (i.e. all eigenvalues of $A$ have real part zero) and $B$ be another arbitrary matrix.

Now assume that the eigenvalues of $A+B$ have all a negative $(<0)$ real part, so they may be complex, but the real part is negative.

Does this impose any obvious conditions on $B$, the spectrum of $B$ etc.?

I am just looking for interesting properties of $B$ in such a scenario and I am very curious to hear about your ideas.

Comment: Can we assume, for example, that the matrix $B$ is symmetric?  Perhaps that it is normal?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom not per se, because I don't want to cut off any interesting results for the most general case. though I'd say that if you think that the general case will not give anything useful, I invite you to make additional assumptions :-)

Comment: One nice condition: if $A$ and $B$ commute, then $B$ must have eigenvalues with negative real part.  You might be able to do something nice then with $\|AB - BA\|$.

Comment: The sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the trace of a matrix, and the trace of $A+B$ is the trace of $A$ $+$ the trace of $B$, which would give us that the sum of the real parts of the eigenvalues of $B$ is less then minus the sum of the eigenvalues of $A$.